# Edit Recent Posts to Display HTML-Tables with Markdown

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editing, markdown

Users have been using $\rm\LaTeX$'s `array` environment for displaying tables.  For instance, in the [MathJax Tutorial's "Table" section](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29979/161490),

```
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Day}} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Credit}}
& \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Debit}} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Total}}\\\hline
 0                                       & 0    & 0   & 10000 \\\hline
 1                                       & 100  & 500 & 9600 \\\hline
 2                                       & 0    & 400 & 10000 \\\hline
 3                                       & 1000 & 500 & 10500
\end{array}
```

gives

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Day}} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Credit}}
& \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Debit}} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Total}}\\\hline
 0                                       & 0    & 0   & 10000 \\\hline
 1                                       & 100  & 500 & 9600 \\\hline
 2                                       & 0    & 400 & 10000 \\\hline
 3                                       & 1000 & 500 & 10500
\end{array}

Should we accept edits that convert recent posts (say, published within 2 days) containing tables rendered by $\rm\LaTeX$'s `array` environment into the corresponding Markdown syntax?

```
| Day | Credit | Debit | Total |
| --: | --: | --: | --: |
| 0 | 0    | 0   | 10000 |
| 1 | 100  | 500 | 9600 |
| 2 | 0    | 400 | 10000 |
| 3 | 1000 | 500 | 10500 |
```

| Day | Credit | Debit | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 10000 |
| 1 | 100 | 500 | 9600 |
| 2 | 0 | 400 | 10000 |
| 3 | 1000 | 500 | 10500 |

Comment: Why should we accept such edit suggestions?  The array environment seems to suit the purpose just fine.  If the *only edit being suggested* is to transform into markdown, then I think it ought to be rejected as providing "no improvement whatsoever."

Comment: It's been awhile since you posted this, so perhaps enthusiasm has waned.  In any case here is a link to [the announcement on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).

Comment: Related (from an accessibility viewpoint): [Are Markdown tables superior to MathJax arrays for accessibility?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11370) at [rpg.meta.se].

Answer (score 1):

Does the Latex array work for accessibility tools the same way as the tables? If the markdown is more accessible than the array, then this is an inclusivity issue, and these edits are improving the post, and should be approved.

On the flipside, unless you can demonstrate that the markdown tables and LaTeX arrays are functionally identical in every way, and someone has made the effort to edit them into the known-accessible and Stack Exchange-fixable format, why would you reject that effort, purely on the basis that *you personally* (meant here generically addressing all such users, not a specific user here or elsewhere) don't see the difference?

Comment: If I were more knowledgeable about HTML semantics, I would have posted an answer for my own question.  I believe that web developers prefer standard HTML syntax rather than a rendered result using an external JS library.